# eclipse try-with-resource template?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, try-with-resources

Eclipse supports try-with-resource, somewhat like this:

```
try(Outputstream resource = new FileOutputStream(file)){
// do something...
}
```

It has been years since this featured added to eclipse, but there is no template "try-with-reousource". only exists one is "try-catch".

I tried to make template, like `try($type{} ${localVar} = new $type{}){ {$cursor{} }`, but was useless. (non-AutoClosable types were also suggested)

Is there any useful try-with-resource template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "try-with-resource" template included in Eclipse.

There is an open issue for it: [Bug 351864 - [1.7][templates] Add 'try-with-resource' template](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351864)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 4.22 (Q4 2021, 7 years later) might offer that feature:

> ### [Surround with try-with-resources quickfix](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.22/jdt.php#surround-with-try-with-resources-quickfix)
>
> A new quickfix has been created to offer Surround with `try-with-resources` for resource leaks and potential resource leaks when the resource in question implements AutoCloseable.
>
> Examples of quickfix:
>
> [image: Unclosed Resource -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.22/images/unclosed-closeable.png]
>
> [image: Potentially Unclosed Resource]